# Delineate Built-Up Areas not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have been experimenting with the Delineate Built-Up Areas tool in ArcToolbox and have been unable to get it to properly work.  The tool works properly without giving error messages, however I get an empty output.  My paramenters are as follows:

**Input Building Layers**: 250 foot buffered point poly's

**Identifier Field:** An empty short integer field named 'Identifier'

**Grouping Distance**: 2 miles

**Minimum Detail Size**: 5 feet

**Edge Features**: a layer of polygons which contain the input features

**Minimum building count**: 2

**Environment>Reference Scale**: 5000.

I get the message that some features have geometries below tolerance in the GUI but other then that it is successfully completed but I have an empty dataset.  I am just trying to get the tool to work so I can tweak it as needed to get the desired result.

Comment: No output in my case also. The same projection of input. And Result window shows success...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163760)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered on the same problem, recently. I solved this issue making sure that the features both in **Input Buildings** and **Egde Features** were in the same **Map Projection**, since they were from different datasets (in my case I converted to metric - WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_35N, however it is not necessary to project, it works for non-projected CS, too).